# I can't freeze my camera by a script even though it shows that it's freezing all the axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to find the answer for the last 3 hours and I couldn't find anything that would help me. It shows that the camera already has constraints when it enters the cube, so it works, but it doesn't because it's not freezing the camera. I don't know what to do already.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LCOE : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject cam;

    Rigidbody rig;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            cam.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;

        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            cam.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a mixed/virtual reality app? Meaning the Camera is controlled externally via the according SDK?

Comment: derHugo No it's just a camera attached to a character.

Comment: did you try to simply set `ca.GetComponnet<Rigidbody>.isKinematic = true;` ?

Comment: derHugo Yes I already tried doing that. That didn't work as well. I even tried setting it manually in the editor but that didn't work either

Comment: well how is your character moved? Maybe the Rigidbody isn't even involved?

Comment: derHugo It's really about the camera, but the character does move with the help of rigidbody

Comment: it seems like the script itself works, but the camera still continues moving even though all the axis are blocked by the constraint.

Comment: as said ... maybe it is moved in a different way ... could you show your code?

Comment: Nevermind. I already figured it out. Thanks for trying to help :D

Comment: @Ranbee if you found the solution you should leave it on this post in case others have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing constrains or isKinematic on Rigidbody will only disable physics movement, but it will still move together with parent object. Your camera should not be child of player and script attached to camera should look like that:

```
class MyCamera : MonoBehaviour{
    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 offset;
    public bool isMovementDisabled;

    void LateUpdate(){
        if(isMovementDisabled)
           return;
        transform.position = target.position + offset;
    }
}
```

Or use cinemachine